# Capture All BroadCastReceivers in android

Tags: android, emulation

I need to capture the all broadcastreceiver trigger by the application using the emulator. Is it possible to log these broadcast receivers to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use it. if you want to log it on your activity just register your activity for this purpose.
additionally you can log it from your services that broadcast something.

Comment: I need to capture the other applications BroadCastreceivers. These are not my applications. I need to capture other peoples' application BroadCastReceivers